# How to use regex in django query to get the shortest match?

Tags: python, django, regex, django-orm

I have some bunch of entries in a column of a `Postgres` database that looks like below

```
Abcd/*
Abcd/dir1/*
Abcd/dir1/dir2/*
Abcd/dir1/dir2/dir3/*
```

I am using `django ORM` to access this information like below

```
given_path = "/some/path"
access_obj = Access.objects.get(dir_id=given_path) #dir_id is the column name
```

Now given a path, I need to find the earliest match (any path after `*` is allowed, hence don't search further) and give the result back.

What I mean is say a path is given `Abcd/dir1/dir2`, since my first entry itself is `Abcd/*` so I don't need to look any further and return the first row object itself.

Currently I try to fetch using `__icontains` check like below

```
access_obj = Access.objects.get(dir_id__icontains=given_path)
```

But it would return all the matches and then I am unable to figure out how to target the first match (in this case) and query the object.

I am aware `django` supports `regex` on queries but I am not sure what to apply here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You just want the shortest matching path? You could sort by the length of the path and return the shortest?

Comment: @IainShelvington  wow that's a great idea. I could do that by looping through the result set and checking the path length. Any idea if it can be done inline ie in the query itself?

Comment: I think I have a potential solution, added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate each matching result with the length of the matching path, you can then order by this length and select the first/shortest result

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length

access_obj = Access.objects.filter(
    dir_id__icontains=given_path
).annotate(
    l=Length('dir_id')
).order_by(
    'l'
).first()
```

Comment: @Ian thanks mate! This works as I expected.